# How do I use quotation marks properly when echoing properties and attributes through PHP and SQL)?

Tags: php, sql, properties, echo, quotes

```
while ($row = $arr_result ) {   
            echo "<option value='" . $row['fallacytype'] .  "'>" . $row['fallacytype'] . "</option>";               
        }
```

I am trying to create a  and  menu in html by using the string values in my SQL table.

I've confirmed that the rest of my code (not shown here, but can be provided if needed to diagnose), is working. The only thing that goes wrong is that my loop up there becomes infinite (i know this because it creates infinite     sql    value).

I've looked up and tried all the variations of quotation marks to no avail.
I've checked in w3shool.com, and other video tutorials that my loop syntax is correct.

It seems that the $row variable is not incrementing or moving on to the next value in the loop for some curious reason.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It does matter what is in the $arr_result variable. If this variable does not hold something that equals false, it will loop indefinitely.

Comment: `$row = $arr_result` is an assignment. It has to be an infinite loop.

Comment: that's what I thought too, but I saw two different tutorials do that. 1) w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp 2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqfl51HVodI @ 14:25. OH,it probably has to do with the non "sqli_" versions of the functions... returning different things?

Comment: no, it actually works as an assignment. you don't need to do foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop via following way for all the elements:

```
foreach($arr_result as $row) {   
   echo "<option value='" . $row['fallacytype'] .  "'>" . $row['fallacytype'] . "</option>";               
}
```

Comment: Thank you. that makes perfect sense.